Blazor in WPF, isolation CSS not created
I have followed the steps here to create a WPF Blazor application using ASP.Net Core 6:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/wpf?view=aspnetcore-8.0
However I called my app Sppro Designer
I tested the app name by using this code:
        string projectName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

My problem is when I create a razor page, with razor.css file ie (page.razor.css) an isolation css file is not being created.
In index.html I have:
<link href="Sppro_Designer.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
/* Trying both to be sure */
<link href="Sppro Designer.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Both files are coming back as 404.
I have been looking around some post say things along these lines
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot").UseStaticWebAssets();

however I dont have a builder, or an App, as my services are generated in mainwindow.xaml.cs (remember this is a WPF app)
